# Photogrammetry: Software to modify/correct details in 3D objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, autodesk, blender-2.67

I started to work with 123D Catch and Blender a while ago. I made some photos and created 3D object in 123D Catch. Next step is to put it into Unity.

But before it I need to correct some details (some edges have inappropriate shape, colour is missed in some places etc). 
I tried to import this 3D object into blender but I couldn't upload texture automatically (I watched some tutorials about mapping, but exaples are easy and my object has complicated construction). 
Can anyone reccomend me a software where I can correct basic stuff like egdes, shape or colour easly?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **When downloading the models the textures are included as 1 or more
  image files.**
  you can edit them in any image manipulation software (e.g. Gimp or Photoshop)
- **When opening the model in blender**
  make shure that you use <kbd>file>import>obj</kbd>
  and turn on textured mode :
  [image]
- **Mapping is not neccesary** 
  as the UVs are contained in the model alredy.
- **After editing the shape you can** 
  export the model via <kbd>file>export>obj</kbd> or just drag the .blend file into your assets and let Unity convert it automtically.

**Before you use your model in unity** you should consider **reducing its geometry/detail** as the generated models can be very high poly.
For that purpose, I can recommend "Meshlab"
Further reading: http://www.shapeways.com/tutorials/polygon_reduction_with_meshlab

Comment: Thanks! It works! The problem was that I was firstly importing the file (in solid mode) and than turn on texture mode and it was still blank.